# Is it safe to use user defined variables inside stored procedures in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-8.0, variable

Currently I'm working with Stored Procedures in MySQL and I'm using in some procedures **user-defined variables** and I've seen that type of variables are initialized in the current session and keep their value until the session ends.

I was also working with statements like `select into @user_defined_variable` but I realized that doing that is very risky, specially on logins/authentications.
So the solution in this case was to use the statement `set @user_defined_variable` instead of `select into`.

But I'm really not sure if it's enough using the `set`, because that type of variables will keep their value while the session is not finished.

Now imagine that the server receives several requests at same time on the Stored Procedures that are using the same `@user_defined_variable`, can exist a collision of values in this case? For example, if the stored procedure called `login` uses the user defined variables `@uuidUser` and the stored procedure called `home` also uses the `@uuidUser`, does exist the risk that the `home` procedure uses the value of `@uuidUser` assigned inside the `login` procedure?

**Note**: I'm working with Node.js and I only have one connection to the MySQL instance,I don't create a connection for every request. So the `@user_defined_variables` will always exist.

Comment: User defined variables are per session, but deprecated in MySQL-8.0. Store procedures can have local variables which sounds like what you should be using. Is unclear what value a stored procedure is giving you over an application language implementation. Welcome to DBA stack exchange.

Comment: @danblack Thanks! And yes I've worked with local variables but as you said I should have been working with those variables for all procedures. I will change the code for avoiding future problems.

Comment: @danblack *but deprecated in MySQL-8.0.* ????? O_O Where you have taken this information from???

Comment: *can exist a collision of values in this case?* Absolutely impossible.

Comment: *So the @user_defined_variables will always exist.* User-defined variable exists always by design. Even when it was not accessed/assigned previously. Until the most first assignment the value of UDV is NULL.

Comment: Errata, it was "Support for setting user variables in statements other than SET was deprecated in MySQL 8.0.13", [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-deprecations), not the entire user variables. my appoligies.

Comment: @Akina thank very much! And what I meant about user defined variable will always exist was because I only have one connection from Node js to MySQL, so those variables will be for that connection and for that reason I had the security problem with some Stored Procedures.

Comment: @danblack This is a fiction, see FETCH. AFAIR your citated stmt was changed till "INTO after LOCK" in 8.0.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-defined variables are specific to the session where they were set. They don't leak over to other sessions.

Each session has its own variables. A variable of the same name in a different session does not hold the same value. Just like local variables in any programming language.

Even if you use a connection pool so a given connection is reused by a subsequent request, there is a reset of the session when the connection is recycled. So all session-specific state is discarded. That includes session variables (both system variables and user-defined variables), temp tables, transactions, the session character set, session counters, etc. It would be very bad for security if any of those things leaked over to a subsequent request that reused a connection from the connection pool.

There is no difference with respect to scope or security between `SELECT ... INTO @user_defined_variable` versus `SET @user_defined_variable = ...`. Both assign a value to that user-defined variable. The variable holds its value for the duration of the session, or until it is assigned a different value. At the end of the session, the variable is discarded.

I would also suggest using local variables in your stored procedures or triggers if you need to. You must use `DECLARE` at the top of the stored routine to create such a variable. The scope of the local variable is only the routine where it was created. After that routine returns, the local variables are discarded.

Comment: Thank you! I'm understanding more about this and as you said I'm better changing the user defined variables for local variables.

Comment: About the sessions I guess I understand and as I said I only have one connection from Node to MySQL (I don't close it never) so all those values of user-defined variables will stay there for that connection / session. And using those variables with a `select into` I realized is dangerous, because if the query in `select into` returns null, the variable will use the last value instead of the returned and here was where I had the security problems.

Comment: If the query returns null, it will assign null to the variable. If the query has no result, that's different from returning null, and you're right, `SELECT INTO` will not change the variable, whereas `SET` will change it.

Comment: Oh, so I was wrong with the concept of `SELECT INTO` too.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can test it this way: `SELECT 123 INTO @foo WHERE true` versus `SELECT 123 INTO @foo WHERE false`.

Comment: That's a good example. I tested and it worked as I expected.
I really appreciate your help!